# How to marginalize a Lagrangian density?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, wavefunction, coordinate-systems, non-linear-schroedinger

I'm trying to replicate a result from this paper: *Physical Review A* **76**, 063614 (2007). It's for a class in classical mechanics, so we're only concerned with Lagrangian densities and such. I must marginalize a Lagrangian density, but I'm not sure how to do that.

### **Here's the problem**

I must substitute the Ansatz:
$$
\phi(r,z,t)=\frac{ r^s}{\sqrt{\pi s!\,}\sigma^{s+1}(z,t)}\exp\left[-\frac{r^2}{2\sigma^2(z,t)}\right]f(z,t)
$$
into the lagrangian density:
$$
\mathcal{L}(\Psi^{},\Psi^{\dagger},\partial_{\mu}\Psi,\partial_{\mu}\Psi^{\dagger})=
\frac{i}{2}\left(\Psi^{\dagger}\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}-\Psi\frac{\partial\Psi^{\dagger}}{\partial t}\right)-
\frac{1}{2}|\nabla\Psi|^{2}-\frac{1}{2}(x^{2}+y^{2})|\Psi|^{2}-\pi g|\Psi|^{4},
$$
where
$$
\Psi(\vec{r},t)=\phi(r,z,t)e^{is\theta},
$$
And from there **marginalize** the density so that it only **depends on $z$**. This is where I'm not entirely sure if I'm doing it right.

### **My attempt**

In cylindrical coordinates, $dv=r\,dr\,d\theta\, d\psi\,dz$ for $r>0$ and $0 \leq \psi <\infty$. Then I only integrated with respect to $r$ and $\psi$; is that right?

After substituting and differentiating with respect to time, and focusing only on the first Lagrangian density term, (ignoring the $i/2$ term):
$$
\left(f^{\dagger}\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}-f\frac{\partial f^{\dagger}}{\partial t}\right)\int_{0}^{2\pi} \,d\psi \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{r^{s+1}}{\sigma^{s+1}(z,t)\sqrt{\pi s!}}\exp\left[-\frac{r^2}{2\sigma^2(z,t)} \right]\,dr
$$

$$
=\frac{2\pi}{\sigma^{s+1}(z,t)\sqrt{\pi s!}}\left(f^{\dagger}\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}-f\frac{\partial f^{\dagger}}{\partial t}\right)\int_{0}^{\infty} r^{s+1}\exp\left[-\frac{r^2}{2\sigma^2(z,t)}\right]\,dr.
$$
Is this how the marginalization is done? The idea is a density that only depends on $z$.

Comment: Yes, to obtain the marginal density with respect to $z$ you just need to integrate the rest of variables. Check [marginal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution#Marginal_probability_density_function) (although not a probability in this case, it is analogous).

Comment: Thank you! I have a further question, is it something one regularly posts on the same question, or do I make another one?

Comment: @Kantomk Just ask it here. You'll be advised to write a fresh question if it's big enough.